# typescript switch enum key

Tags: typescript, enums

given an enum :

```
export enum COLOR {
   BLUE= 'blue',
   DARK_BLUE='blue',
   RED= 'red',
}
```

i want do a switch case like that :

```
function foo(colorKey: string){
//for exemple colorkey has value : DARK_BLUE
  switch (colorKey){
    case COLOR.BLUE:
      //do somthing:
    case  COLOR.DARK_BLUE:
      //do another thing
}
```

This does't work because COLOR.DARK_BLUE returns the value ( 'blue' ) and not the key (DARK_BLUE),
and I want to compare the value of the switch with the key of the enum and not with it's value.

EDIT :
[this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg8gGTgJSgbwLACgpQEIICqAolALxQDkARgDZjCUA02uAIgILIDSA%20gSXJU6DZqyjJibIZQBOwACZisAX2zYAZmBABjAC4BLAPYgoGo0YAUOo7SOzuwAJ4AuKAGtnRjVD1OADsDesIgoAJTo4gDOAO4GejoAFlDWtvaOThGYOLhQOgCGUcBUAsSULuK4BUVUnDz8RGUVObgA9K0KRlBRRhB6iQYgAObNuXmFxZSSbOWVUO2dUPkgRv3Asr4Dw%20JqOdi7QA) is ok, it's true that we have IntelliSense when we call foo and it is good, but the problemes are :

1. When we are writing the switch case of foo, we have to copy_past all the values of the enum (lose of intelisence).
2. If one day somone add a new value to the enum, the compiler will not be able to detect that the switch case in not more exhaustive.

This is why i was still searching for a better approach.

I came up with my own solution, i'll post it as soon as i have time, but to sum up, i created an enum whose  values are the same as the key.

And the values of the old enum are now stocked in a different constant object.
My concuslion is that in typescrpit enums, we cannot stock 2 informations in an enum and still be able to access it correctly.

I'm still looking for a better solution if you have one

Comment: I see a [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68800990/2887218) that is exactly what I would post here.  Since you said you don't like that one, please consider editing this question to delineate what sorts of solutions you would accept and articulate what your problems are with potential solutions that you wouldn't accept.  In particular for [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NlplON) you say you "lose intelisense of the enum", but I don't know what that means as [IntelliSense looks okay to me](https://i.imgur.com/FyrQJdD.png).  Could you explain? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Simply check it the key is in enum...

```
function foo(colorKey: string){
  const color = COLOR[colorKey as keyof typeof COLOR];
  if (color) {
    // It is one of enum values
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: i think you misunderstood the question, try read it again

Comment: Still same, please provide an example of input and output to give us a clue